# Find Entities with NHibernate from other Object

Tags: c#, nhibernate, repository

I have a really big problem:
I am trying to find Entities (with NHibernate) using other object. Example:
Emplyee (entity) -> { Name, LastName, Email, Address }
EmplyeeSearchFilters (filters object) -> { Name, LastName, Email, Address }
Then, I want to pass EmployeeSearchFilters to the Repository (generic) and automatically find with NHibernate using the properties that are not null. Example:
EmployeeSearchFilters -> { Name = "Nelly", LastName = null, Email = "@fibertel.com", Addres = null }
Someone have idea how can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `NHibernate.Criterion.Example` criterion can be used for that purpose. Doc can be found [here](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querycriteria-examples)

Comment: Hey, I have a new problem. Example: Employee->City is other entity, that I can search by it. I try creating a new instance of the City Class, getting from the db, concating property name with property of the City entity, but nothing. Have you idea how can a resolve it?

Comment: There is an example (in the doc) that is similar to what you're trying to attempt: Create a sub-criteria on the `City` property and add an `Example` criterion with the property `Name` set.

Answer (score 1):

You can use linq by use this function:

```
    public virtual List<T> RetrieveByList<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return Session.Query<T>().Where(predicate).ToList<T>();
    }
```

and can use like this:

```
    RetrieveByList<Customer>(x=>x.Name == "Nelly" && x.LastName == null && x.Email == "@fibertel.com" && x.Addres == null)
```

and you can use with dynamic predicate http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28580/LINQ-and-Dynamic-Predicate-Construction-at-Runtime